# Can index.html read needing .js file in angular.js 1.x version?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

users have permission to go over menu.

when A user need menu_1.js file
but B user don't need menu_1.js file as well as haven't to go there

I want to read needing js file in index.html in angular.js ver 1.x.

Can I resolve this?

Thank u your answer.

Comment: Yes, you can. There's a way to include such script just for specific user in js

Comment: You can use multiple ui-view in such kind of problem.

Comment: I'm going to add route provide in controller and then index.html includes such this controller. cause menu don't want to come a user who don't have permission.

Comment: so I don't want I use ng-if or ng-view etc. just I want index.html to include jsfile Dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help

```html
<footer ng-if="userA">
<!-- Call the script here -->
</footer>

<footer ng-if="userB">
<!-- Call the script here -->
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you. but I don't need this. cause this way has problem. if B user know menu_1 url, B user can go there.

Comment: You can check that in .run() method @EddyKim